# How can I get the windows epoch timestamp in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, epoch

Windows epoch time is a 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601.
Linux epoch  measures time by the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

My question is: how to get windows timestamp epoch in a windows system with c++?

Comment: the epoch is obviously 0 in any time system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is

```
static const __int64 NC_SEC_FILETIME = 10000000;
static const __int64 NC_SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH = 11644473600; //windows epoch starts(1601-01-01T00:00:00Z); UNIX/Linux epoch starts (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)

const auto p1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
__int64 time_linux =    p1.time_since_epoch().count();
time_windows = NC_SEC_FILETIME * time_linux + NC_SEC_FILETIME + NC_SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH;
```

and it works good.

Smart solution I found:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
    __int64 getEpochTime()
    {
        FILETIME ft;
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
        const __int64 time = (__int64(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
        return time;
    }
```